# specific tasks should be only for single server

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Few ansible tasks should be run only once instead of multiple times

I am still learning the ansible and  I wrote an ansible playbook which contains a task like echo username to a log file but it is echoing the output everything when it run on remote hosts. Any help is appreciated.

```
- name: user
shell: echo "$LOGNAME user"  >> /tmp/audit_list
delegate_to: localhost

- name: remote hosts 
action: shell  echo "remote host is {{ansible_fqdn}}" >> /tmp/audit_list
delegate_to: localhost
```

The /tmp/audit_list looks like below:

```
 tommy user
 tommy user
remote host is apache1
```

Since i am running the above playbook on 3  servers, it is printing the user name three times but i want to print it only one time followed by all remote hosts where the playbook was executed.

Below is the desired output i am looking for

```
tommy user
remote host is apache1 
remote host is apache2
remote hoost is apache3
```

Comment: so what's wrong with [`run_once: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-run-once)? Also, be careful of using `>>` unless you have `--forks 1` because that can can execute concurrently and cause unexpected behavior (there's no locking for that file). Also, `action: shell` is some seriously old syntax that you should definitely avoid

Answer (score 0):

You need *run_once*. See example below

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: user
      shell: echo "$LOGNAME user"  >> /tmp/audit_list
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
    - name: remote hosts 
      shell:  echo "remote host is {{ansible_fqdn}}" >> /tmp/audit_list
      delegate_to: localhost


> cat /tmp/audit_list 
root user
remote host is test_01
remote host is test_02
remote host is test_03
```